# Method read() not invoked, however its code is executed

Tags: java, interface, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to understand Java code from my book, and I have came across this:

```java
package com.company;

public class CharGenerator {
    char []small_letters= "abcdefghijklmnoprstuwyz".toCharArray();
    char []capital_letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUWYZ".toCharArray();
}
```

```java
package com.company;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.util.Random;

public class CharGeneratorAdapter extends CharGenerator implements Readable{
    private int count;
    CharGeneratorAdapter(int count){
        this.count = count;
    }
    Random v = new Random(4);
    @Override
    public int read(CharBuffer cb) throws IOException {
        if (--count == 0){
            return -1;
        }
        for (int counter = 0; counter < 3; ++counter) {
            cb.append(small_letters[v.nextInt(20)]);
            cb.append(capital_letters[v.nextInt(20)]);
        }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

```java
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.nio.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner x = new Scanner(new CharGeneratorAdapter(10));
        while(x.hasNext()){
            System.out.println("\n");
            System.out.println(x.nextLine());
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not exactly sure, how is it possible, that method read() is never invoked, but its code is executed, and program is working just fine.

Comment: Oh, the `read(...)` method ***is*** definitely called, just not directly by you. Rather, it is called behind the scenes by the Scanner object.

Comment: Extending on @HovercraftFullOfEels' comment: This mechanism is also known as the [Hollywood Principle](https://wiki.c2.com/?HollywoodPrinciple).

Comment: @Turing85: that is the first time that I've heard that term before. Thank you for the edumacation!